# Play 2.5 Scala unresolved dependency suddenly

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I have a project running play 2.5 with Scala which was working fine until tonight. I suddenly cannot pull a bunch of dependencies .. I do not know what to do .. Here is the stacktrace:

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: io.netty#netty-
codec;4.0.36.Final: not found
unresolved dependency: io.netty#netty-handler;4.0.36.Final: not found
unresolved dependency: org.asynchttpclient#netty-resolver-dns;2.0.2: not found
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.netty#netty-reactive-streams;1.0.4:not found
unresolved dependency: org.javassist#javassist;3.20.0-GA: not found
unresolved dependency: org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.21: not found
unresolved dependency: oauth.signpost#signpost-core;1.2.1.2: not found
unresolved dependency: oauth.signpost#signpost-commonshttp4;1.2.1.2:not found
unresolved dependency: com.sndyuk#logback-more-appenders;1.4.1:not found
unresolved dependency: org.komamitsu#fluency;1.1.0: not found
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe#config;1.3.1: not found
unresolved dependency: org.scaldi#scaldi_2.11;0.5.8: not found
unresolved dependency: org.scaldi#scaldi-play_2.11;0.5.14: not found
unresolved dependency: org.scaldi#scaldi-akka_2.11;0.5.7: not found
unresolved dependency: org.scaldi#scaldi-jsr330_2.11;0.5.9: not found
unresolved dependency: org.json4s#json4s-native_2.11;3.3.0: not found
unresolved dependency: org.json4s#json4s-ext_2.11;3.2.11: not found
unresolved dependency: com.sksamuel.avro4s#avro4s-core_2.11;1.6.4: not found
unresolved dependency: org.apache.avro#avro;1.8.1: not found
unresolved dependency: org.apache.kafka#kafka_2.11;0.10.1.1: not found
unresolved dependency: org.aspectj#aspectjrt;1.8.6: not found
unresolved dependency: com.sksamuel.elastic4s#elastic4s-core_2.11;5.4.0: not found
unresolved dependency: com.sksamuel.elastic4s#elastic4s-jackson_2.11;5.4.0: not found
unresolved dependency: com.sksamuel.elastic4s#elastic4s-http_2.11;5.4.0: not found
....
```

How can I fix this ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The project is in Play 2.5.18 and scala 2.11.11

Answer (score 0):

I found the version at maven central: https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cio.netty%7Cnetty-codec%7C4.0.36.Final%7Cjar

Are you importing the dependency explicitly? Or is it a recursive dependency?

Comment: It is a recursive dependency. Probably pulled from play

Answer (score 0):

If you suddenly can't locate any dependencies then it looks a lot like you've got a transient network issue preventing you from making downloads.

Suggestions:

1. Try again later.
2. Try downloading the dependencies directly in your browser and see if they work.

Comment: The thing is that whenever I clone my project on another laptop, it is working perfectly ...

Comment: Try cleaning or renaming your `~/.ivy2` folder. Also try manually deleting all `target` folders inside your project. To verify network issues, verify that manually downloading works the same on both laptops.